# Microsoft Speech API для русского языка

Tags: c++, распознавание-речи, microsoft-speech-sdk

Я хотел поиграться с Microsoft Speech API. За основу взял код из [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358823/sapi-identifying-more-than-2-properties) и всё получилось! Я пытался изменить грамматику для распознавания русского языка. Файл с грамматикой выглядит так:

```
<GRAMMAR LANGID="419">
    <DEFINE>
        <ID NAME="TEST" VAL="1"/>
    </DEFINE>
    <RULE NAME="TEST" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE">
        <L>
            <P>Привет</P>
            <P>Пока</P>
        </L>
    </RULE>
</GRAMMAR>
```

Код программы взят из [упомянутого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358823/sapi-identifying-more-than-2-properties). Но я столкнулся с проблемой, строка:

```
HRESULT hr = cpRecoGram->LoadCmdFromFile(L"D:\\data\\test\\reco_ru.cfg", SPLO_STATIC);
```

возвращает **0x80045052** (-2147200942): `An attempt to load a CFG grammar with a LANGID different than other loaded grammars`.

Кто-нибудь знает, что изменить в программе или может быть на машине, чтобы код мог работать с грамматиками для русского языка?

Окружение: Windows 10 Home, Visual Studio 2017

Comment: LANGID несколько иной у русского языка https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/intl/language-identifier-constants-and-strings хекс 0х0419 не является числом 419

Comment: @NewView КМК, LANGID указан [правильно](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms723632(v%3dvs.85)#attributes)

Comment: Поставьте langid 1049, и попробуйте с этим числом. :) https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter